# Individual ID's pdf print by Laravel8

Tags: laravel

I'm studying laravel using this gentleman's awesome code.

https://github.com/savanihd/Laravel-8-CRUD/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php

I use Laravel Framework 8.48.2

I would like to add PDF pritabile view to each ID's "show" page

I could success PDF export using this simple test page.

```
public function generate_pdf() {

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('products.generate_pdf');
    return $pdf->stream('yokoya_test.pdf');

}
```

so I had been trying to add PDF export to "show" function .
Here is my current code

Controller

```
public function each_print(Product $product)
{
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('products.each_print');
    return $pdf->stream('each_print.pdf');
}
```

original index.blade.php code is this

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('products.show',$product->id) }}">Show</a>
```

I changed this as below

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('products.each_print',$product->id) }}">Print</a>
```

Here is my current WEB.php

```
Route::get('products/each_print', [ProductController::class, 'each_print']); 
Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
```

but I got this error

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
> Route [products.each_print] not defined.
> C:\xampp0827\htdocs\lara\ic0630-simple\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:427

Could you teach me right code please?

> UPDATE

index.blade.php

https://jsfiddle.net/diessses/m72bs54r/1/

each_print.blade.php

https://jsfiddle.net/diessses/8Lg5wot3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need define the name to the route like:

```
Route::get('products/each_print/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'each_print'])->name('products.each_print');
```

UPDATED
first refactor your code in the index blade table like:

```
<td>

<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('products.show',$product->id) }}">detail</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('products.edit',$product->id) }}">edit</a>
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('products.each_print',$product->id) }}">Print</a>                    
   
<form action="{{ route('products.destroy',$product->id) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">×</button>
</form>

</td>
```

and in the each_print function pass the product instance to the view like:

```
public function each_print(Product $product)
{
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('products.each_print', ['product' => $product]);
    return $pdf->stream('each_print.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! index.blade appear! but when I click each record's show page for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/each_print?8 I got ErrorException Undefined variable: product  error. Is this controller problem? Could you teach me more please?

Comment: normally, and in a resource component, the show function must bind to the related view a post instance. You can see in any resource or any CRUD example in the web. I suggest you take a look at them and see how this normal functions work and you can get a hit to start using laravel. The rest are in the Laravel documentation. Once you give steps on that, came here with any issue related with your codding efforts and you can get the needed help

Comment: the 'products.each_print' blade are expecting for a product instance?

Comment: Thank your again for helping me. I'm sorry I can't follow your question mean. I used to use not "resource" CURD sample before. but This time I used this. I would like to add pdf fuction on this show. Is there any way to fix?

Comment: post your index blade and also the product.each

Comment: Dear @Prospero Thank you very much ! I post two blade files.

Comment: Thank you very much . I tried your code but I got this  Undefined variable: product.

Comment: OMG, sorry. is the route model binding, Route::get('products/each_print/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'each_print'])->name('products.each_print');

Comment: Please don't be sorry . I tried your web.php but I got same ErrorException
Undefined variable: product .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234595/discussion-between-prospero-and-bluetail).